# How to automatically determine the CUDA block size and grid size for a 2D array?

Tags: c++, image-processing, cuda

how to determine block size and grid size automatically for 2D array (e.g. image processing) in CUDA?

CUDA has `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize()` function to calculate block size for cuda kernel functions automatically. see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OCCUPANCY.html). In this case, it works well for 1D array.

For my case, I have a 640x480 image.

How to determine the block/grid size?
I use:

```
////image size: 640x480


int x_min_grid_size, x_grid_size, x_block_size;
int y_min_grid_size, y_grid_size, y_block_size;

cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize
(
    &x_min_grid_size, &x_block_size,
    my_cuda_kernel,
    0, image.width()
);
cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize
(
    &y_min_grid_size, &y_block_size,
    my_cuda_kernel,
    0, image.height()
);

x_grid_size = (image.width()  + x_block_size - 1) / x_block_size;
y_grid_size = (image.height() + y_block_size - 1) / y_block_size;

dim3 grid_dim(x_grid_size, y_grid_size);
dim3 block_dim(x_block_size, y_block_size);

my_cuda_kernel<<<grid_dim, block_dim>>>(<arguments...>)

////check cuda kernel function launch error
cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
if(cudaSuccess != error)
{
    std::cout<<"CUDA Error! "<<cudaGetErrorString(error)<<std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

**Question 1**
Can I calculate block/grid size using this method?

For this code, I got an error after the kernel function launched.

```
CUDA Error! invalid configuration arguments
```

If I set `x_block_size = 32; y_block_size = 32` manually, it works and has no error.

Can I ask why CUDA get `invalid configuration arguments` error message? It seems that I cannot use `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize()` directly for 2D array?

***Potential Solution***
I got an idea about the potential solution:

What if I calculate thread number first, and then use `cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize()` calculate block size for 2D array:

```
////total_thread_num = 640x480 = 307200
int total_thread_num = image.width * image.height;

////compute block/grid size
int min_grid_size, grid_size, block_size;
cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize
(
    &min_grid_size, &block_size,
    my_cuda_kernel,
    0, total_thread_num
);

grid_size = (total_thread_num + block_size - 1) / block_size;

//launch CUDA kernel function
my_cuda_kernel<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(<arguments...>);
```

In my_cuda_kernel, it computes the corresponding index based on image size:

```
__global__ void my_cuda_kernel()
{
    //compute 2D index based on 1D index;
    unsigned int idx = BlockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int row_idx = idx / image.width;
    unsigned int col_idx = idx % image_width;

    /*kernel function code*/

}
```

**Question 2**
If the method in Question 1 is not feasible, can I use the method above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1 Can I calculate block/grid size using this method?

No.

It is important to remember than these API calls provide the occupancy maximizing *number of threads per block* and not the block dimensions. If you run the API twice in each direction, you will likely get an illegal block size when the two values are combined. For example, if the occupancy maximizing thread count for a kernel was 256, then you could wind up with a 256 x 256 block size, which is far larger than 1024 total threads per block, thus the launch failure.

> Question 2 If the method in Question 1 is not feasible, can I use the method above?

In principle, that should work, although you are taking a small performance penalty because the integer modulo operation isn't particularly fast on the GPU. Alternatively, you could calculate a 2D block size which satisfies your needs from the maximum threads per block return by the API.

For example, if you just want blocks with 32 threads in the block dimension which you will map to the major order of your data (for memory coalescing), then just divide the thread count by 32 (noting that the API will always return a round multiple of 32 threads per block because that is the warp size). So, as an example, if the threads per block return from the API was 384, then your block size would be 32 x 12.

If you really want some sort of tiling scheme which uses square blocks, then it is pretty easy to work out that only 64 (8 x 8), 256 (16 x 16), 576 (24 x 24) and 1024 (32 x 32) are the feasible block sizes which are both square numbers and round multiples of 32. In that case you probably want to select the larger block size which is less than or equal to the total thread count returned by the API.

Ultimately how you choose to do this will depend on the requirements of your kernel code. But it certainly is possible to devise a scheme for 2D block dimensioning which is compatible with the block sizing APIs which CUDA currently exposes